Relation between velocity distribution function and microstate numbers in statistical physics
I know Boltzmann's $H$ is proportional to the entropy ($S$) with the sign difference. And, I know about the entropy $S$ is proportional to the logarithm of inverse probability of microstates appearing $W$ ($S=k \ln W$). I have no idea about relation between $H$ and $W$? In my understanding, $H$ is related to the velocity distribution function $f$, where $f$ stands for the particle numbers found at some restricted velocity space, e.g., at ($v_x$, $v_y$, $v_z$). Because $H$ is related to $W$, so the particle numbers are also related to $W$? Why is that? Both microstate numbers and particle numbers includes both a word of "number" each other, but the microstates seem to have nothing with the particles themselves... I am confusing about difference between these numbers. Should I count the number of combinations having a certain energy from many freely-moving particles where the energy is decided only with their kinetic energy and relate with the number of the involved particles? Is a certain restricted velocity space equivalent to a certain interval of the energy? Please advice.
